# delete array using value not index

Tags: javascript, lodash

must I check B is in which index? How can I get rid of B? says I have a function that receive a param that might be A,B,C

```
let grade = ['A','B','C']
delete grade['B']; // this won't work? 
console.log(grade)
```

Comment: You can use `indexOf` to get the index, and then use `splice` to remove the element at that index from the array.

Comment: `grade.splice(grade.indexOf('B'), 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really committed to the idea of using the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator on an array, you could it as so:

```js
let grade = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
delete grade[grade.indexOf('B')];
```

Note, however, that this does not accomplish what it is that you likely want to do. More clearly, I assume you'd want the operation above to return `['A', 'C']`. It actually does not. Rather, you get an `undefined` at index 1 (where the value `B` previously resided).

```js
console.log(grade);
['A', undefined x 1, 'C']
```

The most appropriate operation to properly displace the `B` from the array would be to use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). For example:

```js
let grade = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
grade.splice(grade.indexOf('B'), 1);

console.log(grade);
['A', 'C']
```

Comment: the second param of splice is needed? what does the 1 for?

Comment: @Alan Jenshen - You can find that in the documentation for the `splice` method.  For example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=control

Comment: Yes. By default, if no second parameter is supplied to the `Array#splice` method, it will use the length of the array less the value of the first parameter as its fallback value.  In this case, that would be `3 - 1 => 2`. Thus, `grade.splice(grade.indexOf('B'))` is the same as `grade.splice(grade.indexOf('B'), 2)`, both of which would leave `grade` equal to `['A']`.

Comment: in what case you need to supply other value than `1` in splice method?

Comment: Only when you want to remove more than one item from the array. The `Number`-type value you supply as a second parameter simply specifies how many items to remove sequentially beginning with the index specified in the first parameter. Read the docs.